# ASPX navbar is out of alignment. It's a few cm out of the left position where it should be

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

navbar out of screen

[image: navbar out of screen]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I didn't set any alignments etc. how do I set the beginning of the navbar to the left side on top of my page?

My code for my Site.Master:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="Default.aspx">Startseite</a></li>
                 <li><a href="Bestellen.aspx">Bestellen</a></li>
                <li><a href="Impressum.aspx">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <hr />
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems that it is working on another screen with a higher resolution. But what is the difference? Where can I adjust this?

Comment: Can you post all of the code from the Site.Master?

Comment: Given the classes I see here, should we assume you're using Bootstrap? If so, what version?

Comment: Pretty much impossible for us to tell with what you have given us. There will be some CSS issue here. Use the developer tools in the browser of your choice, inspect the nav bar container to see what is causing the offset. Also the `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">` should probably be inside the container `div`

Comment: made a little bit of progress. When I change the following lines of code in bootstrap.css in browser debugger it works:

.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

The problem is when I change my bootstrap.css within VisualStudio it somehow gets overwritten...